# MessageBird WhatsApp: Can't move from sandbox mode

Tags: api, facebook, whatsapp, messagebird

We have developed an application to send notification through WhatsApp using MessageBird integration.

In Facebook - WhatsApp Management painel our account is in "Sandbox mode" which means that we can only send up to 10 messages/day to only 2 numbers. Detail: our company is already verified and the account status is approved.

Is there anything we are missing? Any help?

Comment: This probably isn't a question you should be asking here. Try to contact a Facebook representative to help you with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two prerequisites for your phone number to be promoted from the "sandbox mode":

- Your business needs to be verified on Facebook (as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/eZpD9kfpxtM))
- Your WhatsApp Business Account needs to be approved. You can easily check this by navigating to [this page](https://business.facebook.com/settings/info) and finding the account under "Accounts > WhatsApp accounts". After finding the relevant account in that list, select "Settings". Your account status should show up as "verified".

In case you need help verifying your business and/or approving your WhatsApp Business Account, please reach out to MessageBird support. If both of these are in order and your phone number is still in sandboxed mode, this is also something they should be able to help you with.

Comment: Thanks Emile!
Actually both are in order. I think MessageBird is using an outdate certificate from a not approved exhibition name. I will contact them.